# JavaScript interop calls error when using IHttpCLientFactory in Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server app that consumes asp.net core web api. Below is the settings in the server app startup file

```
services.AddHttpClient(
                "webapi",
                client =>
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("Configs").GetSection("APIUrl").Value);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "BlazorServer");
                })
```

Below is the constructor

```
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory client;
    public AuthService(IHttpClientFactory client,ILocalStorageService localStorage,AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.localStorage = localStorage;
        this.authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
    }
```

and the AuthService.Login method that calls the api using the IHttpCLientFactory

```
public async Task<Result> Login(LoginRequestModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            //string baseUrl = "https://localhost:44326/";
            //HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            //var response = await http.PostAsJsonAsync($"{baseUrl}{LoginPath}", model);
            var _httpclient = client.CreateClient("webapi");
            var response = await _httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync(LoginPath, model);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var errors = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<string[]>();

                return Result.Failure(errors);
            }
```

This give the error

> JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.

But when I comment out the IHpptClientFactory instance and uncomment the httpclient instance it's able to call the web api endpoint successfully

Login.Razor component

```
@page "/account/login"
```

```
<div class="mx-auto" style="max-width: 400px; margin-top:0px;">
    <EditForm Model="model" OnValidSubmit="SubmitAsync">

        <ErrorsList ShowErrors="ShowErrors" Errors="Errors" />


        <!-- Default form login -->
        <div class="modal-dialog cascading-modal" role="document">

            <!--Content-->
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!--Header-->
                <div class="modal-header primary-color white-text">
                    <h4 class="title">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <!--Body-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                    <ValidationSummary />
                    <!-- Material input name -->
                    <div class="md-form form-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="eml" @bind-value="model.Email" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <label for="eml">Your email</label>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Material input email -->
                    <div class="md-form form-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
                        <input type="password" id="pwd" @bind-value="model.Password" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <label for="pwd">Your password</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                        <div>
                            <!-- Remember me -->
                            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitches">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches">Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <!-- Forgot password -->
                            <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">
                            Login
                            <i class="fa fa-send ml-2"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p>
                            Not a member?
                            <a href="">Register</a>
                        </p>

                        <!-- Social login -->
                        @*<p>or sign in with:</p>

                            <a href="#" class="mx-2" role="button"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f light-blue-text"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="mx-2" role="button"><i class="fab fa-twitter light-blue-text"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="mx-2" role="button"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in light-blue-text"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="mx-2" role="button"><i class="fab fa-github light-blue-text"></i></a>*@
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/.Content-->
        </div>
    </EditForm>

</div>
```

Login.Razor.cs component

```
public partial class Login
{
    private readonly LoginRequestModel model = new LoginRequestModel();

    public bool ShowErrors { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Errors { get; set; }

    private async Task SubmitAsync()
    {
        var result = await AuthService.Login(model);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            ShowErrors = false;
            ToastService.ShowSuccess("You have successfully logged in");
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
        else
        {
            this.Errors = result.Errors;
            this.ShowErrors = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If possible, you can share the detailed code of that component, so that we can reproduce and troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the component and the class that it calls